# Undefined method 'model_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting a undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class.

In the layout file: [application.html.erb]

```
    <section id="featured">
        <%= render 'subscribers/new' %>
    </section>
```

In the form partial: [views > subscribers > _new.html.erb]

```
    <%= form_for @subscriber, :url => subscribe_path do |f| %> [THIS LINE PRODUCES THE ERROR]
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.text_field :email %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit 'Add me to the list' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

In the subscribers controller: [controllers > subscribers_controller.rb]

```
   def new
     @subscriber = Subscriber.new
   end
```

I'm a beginner at ROR, and I've looked around StackOverflow, but can't find any answers for my specific case.

Comment: You shouldn't use the new for method name, it's reserved word

Comment: Name the action in the subscribers_controller 'create' instead of new.

Comment: @megas it's only reserved as a class method to instantiate objects, not as an instance method. In controllers it's perfectly normal to have a "new" action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What path are you hitting when you are seeing this error?

If you are navigating to any path other than `/subscribers/new` then `@subscriber` will be `nil` and the form will throw the error that you are seeing. You are rendering a form via a partial in your view layout, that layout is rendered (presumably) throughout the app. Thus `@subsriber` won't always be set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing I am trying to achieve is to have this form rendered on every page (essentially as part of the layout). The only reason I want to break it out of the application.html.erb file is because it acts as a "featured" section, that will be updated with whatever I want to feature on the website. Think of it as a header/footer. What would be the best way to achieve this, given that it needs to be a form that is hooked into a specific controller?

Comment: If you want to do that, you have to make sure that whatever you are passing into the `form_for` is not `nil`. Perhaps a better way would be to utilize the `form_tag` helper, and just submit your form to a specific controller that handles featured items.

Comment: As I struggle with form_tag, I'm reading everywhere that it shouldn't be used to update the database (that's what form_for is for). In this instance I want to have an email subscription form render as part of the layout, so form_for seems out of the question since it needs to be rendered by a particular route, but form_tag doesn't tie into my models and controllers. What to do now?

Comment: How about, instead of `form_for @subscriber` doing `form_for @subscriber || Subscriber.new`? That will ensure that you have a subscriber object in your view, even if you didn't initialize it in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are rendering the subscribers/new template directly in the layout, but only initializing a Subscriber in the subscriber controller.

You need to create a subscribers/new.html.erb file (without the leading underscore, so it is not a partial)

Somewhere in your layout file you should have a `yield` call.
When you access /subscribers/new rails renders the new.html.erb template file, and stuffs it in where `yield` is called in the layout.

If you really need this form on every page, you will need to initialize a new subscriber on every page. You could do this with a before filter in the application controller. But then you would not need the new action in the subscriber controller.